# Print out prime Number less than a given number N

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Print out the prime numbers less than a given number N. For bonus points your solution should run in `N*log(N)` time or better. You may assume that N is always a positive integer.

Input sample:

Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename. Each line in this file is one test case. Each test case will contain an integer `n < 4,294,967,295`.

E.g.

```
10
20
100
```

Output sample:

For each line of input, print out the prime numbers less than N, in ascending order, comma delimited. (There should not be any spaces between the comma and numbers) E.g.

```
2,3,5,7

2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19

2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97
```

Here is my solution:

```
public class problem1 {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        File f=new File("C://Users/Rahul/Documents/Projects/r.txt");
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);

        List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<>();
        int p;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;

        while( (s= br.readLine()) != null ) {

                   int a=Integer.parseInt(s);

                   for(int i=2;i<a;i++)
                   {
                       p=0;
                        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
                        {
                             if(i%j==0)
                            p=1;
                       }
                   if(p==0)
                      l.add(i);
                   }
                   String st=l.toString();
                   st=st.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replace(", ", ",");
                   System.out.print(st);
                   System.out.println("\t");
        }

        fr.close();
    }
}
```

My input is :

```
10
50
```

And output is :

```
2,3,5,7
2,3,5,7,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47
```

But when i submit this solution they are not accepting this solution.

But when i put content in document like this:

```
10 50
30
```

I am trying that java program ignore this 50. How to do it ?

Any better solution then this ?
Give me some idea!

Comment: Check out [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I am talking about Complexity.

Comment: Your method is N^2, and a really bad N^2 at that. Sieve methods work well. The actual numbers from CodeEval.com are small--on the order of 1000. My submission used Sieve of Sundaram, and ran in 0.03 sec. In Java, I'd expect it to be more like 0.1 - 0.2, which should still give an adequate score. Even my Java version computes up to 20 million quickly, taking most of its time just printing the output.

Comment: Who in the world would think that this belongs on [su]? (Apparently 2 people)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the extra number in your file you can take only the first number of each line.

Your solution is probably not accepted because in your second line you have printed `2,3,5,7` twice (i.e. the primes of the previous line)

See the example below to fix both problems

```
while( (s= br.readLine()) != null ) {
    String [] numbers = s.split(" ");     // split the line 
    int a = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]); // take only the first one
    ....

    System.out.print(st);
    System.out.println("\t");
    l.clear();  // clear the list before trying to find primes for the new line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename"

You have a hardcoded filename in your solution - use `args[0]` instead.

Othwerwise, your solutions looks OK, although there is some room for improvements regarding the efficiency.